# How to correctly define the get and post routes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, get, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

Recently I've been working with rails. I have a form with form_tag, which receives a helper post from routes.rb. I have the same route in get to access this form, and I have the route in posrt to be able to send the data of the previous form:

```
get 'students/:student_id/monitorings/inscribir', to: 'monitorings#inscribir', as: :inscribir_student_monitoring
post 'students/:student_id/monitorings/inscribir', to: 'monitorings#inscribir', as: :inscribir_student_monitoring_post
```

My question is, how can I separate these routes? Since, according to investigating, this can cause problems, since both have the same address, and really if it is causing me problems, since when entering this link the form is executed automatically.

Do you necessarily have to separate the two routes? And if that is true, how can I do it?
I tried something similar to what rails do with respect to the method get new and post create method but adapted to my case, but it has not worked for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you necessarily have to separate the two routes?

No! Unless your both routes have a **same name**, it won't be a problem. For instance if you have routes like below

```
get 'students/:student_id/monitorings/inscribir', to: 'monitorings#inscribir', as: :inscribir_student_monitoring
post 'students/:student_id/monitorings/inscribir', to: 'monitorings#inscribir', as: :inscribir_student_monitoring
```

then Rails would rails an exception like so

> ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use:
>   'inscribir_student_monitoring'  You may have defined two routes with
>   the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route
>   already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter,
>   you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained
>   here: 
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

Since your routes have a **different name**, this won't be a worry. Though you can shorten your code by using `match`

```
match 'students/:student_id/monitorings/inscribir', to: 'monitorings#inscribir', via: [:get, :post]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. Is that with the current routes that I have if I am having problems, especially with a form, which is in the specified route, when entering that form, the form is executed and shows errors of empty fields. This form goes by the post method, while to enter the page of the form is by the method get.

Comment: @ElPapu I dont see any problem there. The `GET` route will be used to render the form page and the `POST` route will be used to submit the form

Comment: I understand, the other thing that occurred to me was to place the route `POST` and put it in another function of the controller, with this I can separate what the rendering does with the logic of the form, leaving it like this: `to: 'monitorings # newMethod'`

Comment: @Pavan match is deprecated in rails5, any alternative to via?